# Change in media library doesn't affect published articles

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm running a WordPress blog with a lot of published articles and a lot of pictures in the media library. My question is:

Is there a way(plugin?) to make WordPress apply changes I made in the media library(e.g. changing the description/alt text of a picture) to already published articles containing that picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time a media is used by Wordpress on a template, its proper data (excerpt, etc.) sould be loaded.
Try to clean your cache to force Wordpress to reload the data.

Maybe the theme you use on your blog don't use the right fields to populate the alt text of the pictures. Semantically, it should be 'image_alt' and 'post_description'.